# Why does my #version 330 shader run on older opengl?

Tags: opengl, glsl

For about 4 weeks, I have been able to successfully run vertex/fragment shaders marked at the top with:

```
#version 330 core
```

However, I just realized that when I call:

```
cout << "OpenGL version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;
cout << "GLSL version: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << endl;
```

I get:

```
OpenGL version: 3.2.0
GLSL version: 1.50 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
```

Why/how am I able to run these shaders with an older GLSL and OpenGL versions? Should I be using an older shader version? Why am I not getting any errors when running this shader? I am trying to catch them as follows:

```
// Compile vertex shader
glCompileShader(VS);
glGetShaderiv(VS, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &rc);
if(!rc) {
    if(isVerbose()) {
        GLSL::printShaderInfoLog(VS);
        cout << "Error compiling vertex shader " << vShaderName << endl;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I get other compilation errors when I make mistakes in my shader. Should I be getting some error or warning because my shader language is too new? How can I tell what my hardware supports if it can handle something newer than the version it reports?

Comment: are you specifically requesting a GL 3.2 context, when your driver might support a later one?

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I was calling   `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);` and `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);` Removing that causes my versions to display 4.30 for both OpenGL and GLSL. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (and confirmed by your comment), that if you request an OpenGL context older than your driver supports, GLSL shaders with a `#version` tag higher than advertised by `GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION` will still compile. The spec does not directly relate a `GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION` to support for a `#version` tag. It only says "Any number representing a version of the language a compiler does not support will cause an error to be generated." (section 3.3).